# How can I enchant items in Elder Scrolls Arena?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

Is it possible in Elder Scrolls Arena to enchant items like in Morrowind or Oblivion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your title's question, *you* don't enchant items as far as I can tell like you would in other TES games like Morrowind or Oblivion, but you **can purchase them**. As was already pointed out, everything except leather/chain armor can be enchanted.

I can't find anything that tells you how to enchant things yourself, just where to buy them all.

If you open [the wiki link](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Magic_Items) listing all the enchanted items, you'll notice it just lists the costs and the locations you can buy them; Further supporting the thought that you can only buy these items not enchant them yourself.

> Dwarven   -   1250    Skyrim  - Amber Guard   - Mages Guild 
>   Dwarven   -   1250    Skyrim  - Amol  - Mages Guild

Also in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Arena/comments/4pjgy9/how_do_enchanted_weapons_work/) they only mention buying enchanted items, not creating/crafting them.

> "If I **buy** a "Sword of Life Steal"..."

Also from another [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_(Arena)) (Bold mine):

> "Your body is protected by various pieces of armor **you can find at
>   an equipment store**."

Also see the [same wiki's enchanting page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting), the only Elder Scrolls games with enchanting articles are:

> Enchant - A skill in The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind 
>  Enchanting
>   (Oblivion) - Enchanting items in The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion 
>   Enchanting (Skyrim) - Enchanting items in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim
>   
>  Enchanting (Online) - Enchanting items in The Elder Scrolls
>   Online

Comment: Ah, I get it. "Can be enchanted" means those items already have an effect, it doesn't mean I can add effects to un-enchanted items. Thanks, this is a good answer.

Comment: @Ethan Yeah that's what I am taking it as, I went and added some more info to support that claim.

Comment: There definitely was enchanting in daggerfall, it completely broke the game balance but was pretty cool. I couldn't swear about arena though. It's been 20 years or so I guess.

Comment: I was going based off what the wiki listed as having articles on enchanting. There is some in daggerfall but it wasn't listed. Doesn't have any for Arena which is the question

Answer (score 0):

According to this [wiki](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Magic_Items):

> All weapons and plate armor can be enchanted. Leather and chain armor cannot be enchanted, however, so unless you are a Warrior, Ranger, or Knight, magic armor is not for you.

So yes, enchanting items is possible in Elder Scrolls: Arena.

You can find a complete list of all enchanted items [here](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Magic_Items#All_Magic_Items_by_Type).

Comment: Interesting, however this is a list of items I can buy or find, I want to know if I can enchant an item with a custom effect, for example a Cuirass with Fortify Strenght